# Providing const and non-const version of functions

Tags: c++, constexpr

Maybe it is a trivial question, but I can't actually find an answer. If I have a class like in the example below do I need to provide both const and non-const version of functions like in case of std::vector? Would a single constexpr function do the same job?

```
template <typename Type>
class Collection
{
    public:

        virtual ~Collection() {}

        virtual size_t size() noexcept = 0;
        virtual size_t size() const noexcept = 0;
        virtual Type operator[](size_t index) noexcept = 0;
        virtual Type operator[](size_t index) const noexcept = 0;
};
```

Comment: Unless your function *needs* to modify, don't bother with the non-`const` version. You'll want to flag anything that doesn't actually modify anything as `const` out of habit anyway, meaning any `const` instances aren't unnecessarily restricted.

Comment: `constexpr` would be unusual unless you have a collection locked in at compile time. Typo in the question?

Comment: @user4581301 Using `constexpr` is generally a good idea if it can be implemented as `constexpr`. `constexpr` does not restrict the function to only being used in compile time contexts. It allows it to be called in both (compile-time and run-time). Consider `std::vector::operator[]` which is constexpr as of `c++20`.

Comment: C++23 addresses the need to implement multiple similar version of const / non-const / lvalue / rvalue member functions [Explicit object parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter)  _"...This makes it possible to deduplicate const- and non-const member functions, see array subscript operator for an example...."_

Comment: I'll cede that point, but I still think shift from `const` to `constexpr` is likely a typo.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If the non-const version would do the same thing as the const version, then no. If someone has a non-const instance of a class, they can still call const methods.

There are some methods that may need both. Consider your indexing operator. If it instead returned a reference to the type, you would probably want both:

```
virtual Type& operator[](size_t index) noexcept = 0;
virtual const Type& operator[](size_t index) const noexcept = 0;
```

The methods aren't exactly the same because they are returning different types. This would mean that if someone has a const instance of your type, they could not get a mutable reference to an element.

A single constexpr function could do the job as long as the potential const/non-const implementations would be the same.